# How to center a logo on SideMenu using Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode8

I want to Center a logo on the SideMenu and this is the code so far:

```
  UIImageView *logo =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    logo.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"menulogo"];
    logo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    logo.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    logo.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    logo.frame = container.bounds;
    [container addSubview:logo];
    [headerView addSubview:container];
```

Comment: You've set the logo's frame to be identical to the container's, so it *can't* be centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extension to UIView

```
extension UIView {  
func constraintToMidCenterXY(of view: UIView) {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                                 centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor))
}
```

}

Then you can do something like this

```
logo.constraintToMidCenterXY(of: container)
```

Also you should not set logo's frame to container's bounds! that's another problem

The above is a common approach that you can use, `Autolayout`. You can also use `UIStackView`

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to use `Auto Layout` to center your `logo` to the `headerView`. It will adapt accordingly to any iPhone screen size.